# Configure HTTPS for React Application deployed on AWS EC2 in Production mode

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, production

I have React Application which is Deployed on AWS EC2, which is running on http.
But Now I want to make it secure using HTTPS. i.e The React Application needs to be accessed from https://mydomainname.com.
Can some body let me know how can this be achieved.

I have done research on this and  found few links like *https://www.makeuseof.com/create-react-app-ssl-https/* to make it run on https but thats for development Only.

Tries with mkcert library but the mkcert documentation clearly tells that it should be used only for development purpose.

Comment: You can use Certbot and add a SSL certificate.